# How to use double GROUP BY correctly

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper

My problem is that I'm trying to group some data more than once in one query using subquery. For example if I have People with their 'name' and 'gender' like that:

```
   name  gender
('Sarah', 'F')
('Mark', 'M')
('Jessie', 'F')
```

and languages they know in Known_Languages collection:

```
   name     language
('Sarah', 'English')
('Sarah', 'French')
('Mark', 'German')
('Jessie', 'German')
```

I'd like to find people who know more than 1 language and than show the result as the number of multilanguage people in both genders like that:

```
 GENDER        NUMBER OF MULTILANGUAGE PEOPLE
     F                                      1
     M                                      0
```

I know that I can group people by their name like that:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM People NATURAL JOIN Known_Languages
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

But how to obtain result like:

```
     GENDER        NUMBER OF MULTILANGUAGE PEOPLE
     F                                      1
     M                                      0
```

basing on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a derived table to get the people who speak more than one language and `join` it to the `People` table to get the `count` for each gender.

```
select p.gender, count(*) number_of_multilanguage_people
from (SELECT name
      FROM Known_Languages
      GROUP BY name
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t 
join People p on p.name = t.name
group by p.gender
```

Comment: Oh. So all the magic was hidden in using subquery in FROM rather than in WHERE, where I've been trying to use it. Thank you! Works in every data group I tried.

Comment: and few words from me about this solution. It's good, it worked for me, but it's not fully compatible with oracle sql as OSql doesn't support JOIN ON. If someone wants to use something like that in OSql, consider this:                    SELECT gender, count(*) 
      FROM (SELECT name
      FROM Known_Languages
      GROUP BY name
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) NATURAL JOIN People
      GROUP BY gender

Comment: it should have been `JOIN People p ON`. changed it